# Cannot login with flask flask_login

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I created sign up protocol and it worked
But when it came to login, it always check login correct.
I use sqlite3, there isn't much extra code and I put all of them in main.py code
Here is my main.py code

```
db = SQLAlchemy(main)
db.init_app(main)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.init_app(main)

@main.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@main.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    if not user and password != user.password:
        flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    login_user(user)

    return redirect(url_for('profile'))
```

and here is the HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="/login">
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input is-large" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" autofocus="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input is-large" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your password">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="button is-block is-info is-large is-fullwidth">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic error.

```
-    if not user and password != user.password:
+    if not user or password != user.password:
        flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Sorry, stackoverflow editor doesn't support diff syntax. `-` means the line should be deleted, `+` means the line should be added.